# Function to convert letter-number coordinates to 2D array indices

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a board game where my board is a 2D array of lists.

```
self._board = [["A", "B", "C"],
               ["D", "E", "F"],
               ["G", "H", "I"]]
```

How can I write a function that can be used to access each piece by using letter-number coordinates.
So for example I can use the function to get "A" by using converter(A1) or "F" by using converter(B3). I would like to avoid importing any modules.

Comment: Share your code with us even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so assuming your board is immutable in size `pandas` is probably the best choice - it provides the indexing for both columns and rows, so:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(index=list("ABC"), columns=[1,2,3])

# both to assign value and to pull value use .loc[] 
df.loc["B", 3]="x"
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df

     1    2    3
A  NaN  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN    x
C  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: OP explicitly states that they don't want to import a module and for such an easy task it is overkill to import pandas.

Comment: @Asocia - my suggestion is different here - don't reinvent the wheel, just use what you have already, and `pandas` also fits perfectly here I feel. Unless OP would state `I can't import any modules` I think my answer is pretty well justified... @Mark Meyer - I don't, I'm suggesting to use it, as pretty well suited to the assumptions presented by OP..

Comment: Why make the code depend on a 3rd party library if you can manage to solve the problem with just a few lines? It's not reinventing the wheel, you really should think about your dependencies.

Comment: Question is - what are the other assumptions about the board for this project. It's a call to make here based on a big picture, whether this makes sense or not to add `pandas` dependency. I don't feel informed enough to say it doesn't, or that it does. Hence it's a suggestion. You're absolutely right, why it might be wrong idea. However I disagree, that it never makes sense to add 3rd party dependencies. We're not solving the problem for OP - we are giving a suggestion here - that's also what I did..

Answer (score 0):

Pick the first string-input as the row counter, lowercase it and translate it from lecter to number though the dictonary I have created below; pick the second string-input as the column counter, then use these counter to access the board.
 This should do the trick without importing extenal modules:

```
self._board = [["A", "B", "C"],
               ["D", "E", "F"],
               ["G", "H", "I"]]

lecter_to_number = {chr(i + 96): i for i in range(1, 27)}

def pick_element(input):

    row = lecter_to_number[input[0].lower()]
    col = int(input[1])

    return self._board[row - 1][col - 1]

pick_element('B3')
```